# How to identify the number of records processed in some SAP transaction?

Tags: sap

I'm trying to view the total number of records including the processing time in generating a SAP table using a certain transaction code.

Let us take for example I want to view the Vendor Master Data by using the Transaction Code ZGTMM29. Once SAP is done processing and displays the table. I want also to view the total number of records processed above or somewhere in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to do some activities here, first of all you have to make debugging in your  program. SAP has many excellent features within and also you can make use of transaction 'ST05' for tracing, 'SE30' for runtime analysis and you can also make use of 'SE16N' to make some filters.

I have described you what I actually do to achieve what you want.